# Динамичное обновление базы MySQL каждую секунду

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Есть задача реализовать что то вроде очков(баллов) на сайте. Пока пользователь находится на страничке то ему на счет **каждую секунду** капает n-ое кол-во баллов. Естественно эти баллы должны быть сохранены в БД + к тому же одновременно на страничке может находится и 1000 и 10000 человек. Я понимаю что при таких условиях 10 000 UPDATE в БД это очень много. Так вот как можно решить эту задачу, какими технологиями?

Comment: *Пока пользователь находится на страничке то ему на счет каждую секунду капает n-ое кол-во баллов.* Для того, чтобы определить, что пользователь "находится на страничке" (не закрыл браузер), придётся ежесекундно от клиента (из браузера) слать сигналы на сервер. Полагаю, пользователь не сильно обрадуется такому трафику... Уменьшите дискретность (скажем, раз в минуту шлите кодом "он ещё тут"), а также шлите сигнал при переходе со страницы. Всё равно будете получать данные "плюс-минус лапоть".

Comment: Хорошо, но в таком случае не будет начислено точное кол-во баллов. Допустим в секунду чел получает 10 баллов. Он просидел на странице 20 секунд и вышел, то-есть по идее он заработал 200 баллов. Но так как проверка идет раз в минуту эти баллы не начислятся (в этом сервисе только одна страница, также пользователь видит свой счет и как капают баллы. Счетчик на JQuery). Так же эти все данные отправляются AJAX-ом в скрипт проверки и обновления в бд

Comment: Значит, считайте локально, и отсылайте насчитанное только при штатном уходе со страницы. Просто предупредите. А кто ушёл нештатно, не дав браузеру отослать данные, тот ССЗБ. И не забывайте сверять насчитанные баллы и штампы времени входа и выхода.

Comment: Из за задержек в сети и других проблем вы все равно не можете быть уверены, что запросы от клиента приходят регулярно. Единственный путь это передавать веремя когда зашел, временами (реже 1 раза  в сек) передавать так же время и на сервере считать сколько баллов начислить. По возможности предусмотреть все способы покидания сайта и на них так же повесить отправку данных.

Comment: Если это происходит все таки очень часто на стороне сервера вести это в "in memory database", т.е. в каком нибудь memcached или redis и периодически сбрасывать в основную БД. Правда если вы возьмете потенциальное кол-во клиентов, посылающих раз в секунду данные и прикинете сколько запросов в секунду должен уметь обрабатывать сервер вы должны придти к решению, что php вам совершенно не подходит, решения не его основе просто не потянут нагрузку...

Comment: @Mike Так и собирался сделать, но проблема в том что кол-во начисляемых баллов в секунду также динамично и может менятся во время нахождения чела на странице. Если не PHP. то тогда что лучше подойдет для этой задачи по вашему мнению?

Comment: Любой язык позволяющий реализовать полноценную технологию fastcgi, когда запущенный скрипт постоянно находится в памяти и не интерпретируется заново при каждом обращении к серверу. node.js, golang, java, perl и т.п. (фактически все что угодно, кроме php Ж)) Так же можно попробовать положить информацию в redis непосредственно из nginx. Возможно для отправки информации стоит рассмотреть использование WebSocket вместо ajax запросов. тогда даже на php можно написать отдельный сервер поддерживающий эти websocket соединения

Comment: @Mike дак и пхп с opcache  не будет интерпретироваться заново.

Comment: @teran Да, это интересно. А сам php скрипт в таком режиме может иметь какие то свои переменные, не теряющие значений между обращениями клиентов ? У нас например скрипты продолжают держать коннекты к БД, кеши справочников и еще всякую мелочь постоянно.

Comment: @Mike opcache формально дает только скомпилированный опкод. само поведение не меняет, запустился-отработал-закрылся о всеми переменными и т.п.  Но есть всякие APC\APCu\WinCache,которые позволяют кэшировать в памяти объекты, а постоянные коннекты можно держать и средствами драйверов, везде вроде есть `pconnect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем такие мега сложности? Поступите как когда-то сделал VK со счётчикам зарегистрированных пользователей.

Когда пользователь заходит на сайт, ему передаётся его текущее количество баллов. Далее на стороне клиента происходит увеличение баллов на 1 каждую секунду с сохранение на стороне клиента (в случае перезагрузки страницы).

Сервер же в свою очередь сохраняет время захода пользователя и последнее обновление страницы пользователем. Когда связь с пользователем теряется, то высчитывается разница между временем захода пользователя и временем последнего обновления. Эта разница реально начисляется пользователю (делается однократный запрос в БД).

P.S. если вам нужно, например, клиенту отображать время сервера, вы же не будете каждую секунду (или чаще) опрашивать время сервера. Вы однократно получите метку времени и уже её будете обновлять на клиенте (через таймер).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, только что увидел ваше сообщение, но за этот день я тоже пришел к этому выводу который вы написали )